# How produce my curl request with binary data by use of spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have below request that works correctly in curl and all things are OK.
I need to do that by use of spring and RestTemplate.

```
curl 'http://myweb.web.com/upload/temp/myImage.jpg' -X PUT  -H 'Origin:  http://myweb.web.com' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: http://myweb.web.com/new'  --data-binary @/opt/myImage.jpg
```

Comment: this is controller in server side but i need client side code. so i said help me by RestTemplate code

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
public void uploadFileTemplate() throws IOException {
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> bodyMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        bodyMap.add("user-file", getUserFileResource());
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyMap, headers);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/upload",
                HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
        System.out.println("response status: " + response.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("response body: " + response.getBody());
    }

    public static Resource getUserFileResource() throws IOException {
        //todo replace tempFile with a real file
        Path tempFile = <path-to-your-imagefile>
        System.out.println("uploading: " + tempFile);
        File file = tempFile.toFile();
        return new FileSystemResource(file);
    }
```

Comment: thanks , i used it but it is not ok. this code not equivalence to my curl, because curl has ok response and use code get exception. exception wrapped by server and i can not report it

Comment: @abbaskarimi No one will give you end to end running code, you will need to add all other code parts which will be required. I just provided you the template so you can add your requirements.